# Insert value with combine the identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have this table with the identity column `pkid`, how can I generate the `cust_num` as `VIP000000 + <pkid>` when inserting a record like this?

| pkid | cust_name | cust_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | VIP0000001 |
| 2 | May | VIP0000002 |
| 10 | John | VIP0000010 |

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl01]
(
    [pkid] [numeric](9, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cust_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [cust_num] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution based on an `IDENTITY` column is to use a computed column - like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl01
    ADD cust_num AS 'VIP' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(pkid AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED;
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tbl01` without specifying values for `pkid` or `cust_num`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl01 (Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically** increase your `pkid` value, and `cust_num` will contain values like `VIP000001`, `VIP000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

**UPDATE**

Since you can't change your table definition, you will most likely need to use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger - something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgTbl01AddCustNum
AFTER INSERT
ON dbo.tbl01
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl01
    SET cust_num = 'VIP' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(pkid AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
    FROM tbl01
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.pkid = tbl01.pkid;
END;
```

Comment: but i can't alter the table, is it possible handle by the insert statement?

Comment: @user1302236 you didn't put that requirement in your question, so I hope you didn't down-vote Mark because of that? And no you can't use that in your insert, because you don't know your id until after the insert completes. So you either need a trigger - but if you can't modify the table I suspect you can't create a trigger or you need to follow your insert with an update statement.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator: **NOT** if you add the `PERSISTENT` keyword to the computed column specification !

Comment: you are correct, take that back, upvote :)

Comment: @jmvcollaborator: plus I've added a solution *without* changing the table structure now ....